# Is there any way to use backspace/enter natively to go up/down in Finder.app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, shortcut

In macOS, it is hard to constantly press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> while navigating to go up/down in the folder hierarchy.

Is there any way to natively achieve this in using the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys respectively instead, without having to rely on third-party program such as Keyboard Mastero? I tried applying a custom shortcut from settings to Finder.app, but it's not possible to apply <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> as shortcuts at all.

Comment: Cmd/up & down aren't 'back & forward' They are Open containing folder & open selected folder. That's not actually the same thing. Back & Forward are Cmd [  & Cmd ] Which do you actually want? All key commands are on https://support.apple.com/HT201236 from which you'll see the Finder is more keyboard navigable than you could ever get from Windows.

Comment: @Tetsujin You're absolutely right about that – my bad. I meant going up/down in the folder hierarchy. I'll update my post to be clearer. Thanks for the link. It's the Command + Up Arrow, "Open the folder that contains the current folder" shortcut and its opposite counterpart which I am trying to change.

Comment: BTW, what view are you using - some of the commands change depending on view - for instance in column view, just the arrows will do what you need, in List, then you probably want cmd/square bracket, as above.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah, you're right. I do use list view, but the problem is that using the arrow keys to expand folders makes the view become extremely messy. That's why I want to replace the Command keys' functions with the Backspace and Enter keys.

Comment: In list view, just right & left arrows will open close a folder, Cmd/Opt/ arrow will open or close the entire folder structure below that - a handy one if you were digging deep down a hierarchy & want it all to close.